# adding gRPC dependency to Rocksdb's CMakeLists

Tags: cmake, grpc, rocksdb

I'm trying to use gRPC directly in rocksdb's source code

```
LogAndApplyClient log_and_apply_client(grpc::CreateChannel(
      secondary, grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials()));
```

log_and_apply_client is a basically class I wrote used for making rpcs calls, and it depends on the Stub Code generated by Protobuf. And I'm adding it directly into rocksdb's source code.

To resolve the grpc dependency, I'm adding dependency into rocksdb's CMakeLists.txt file using the CMakeLists example provided by the gRPC.
I installed gRPC and protobuf in Ubuntu18.04 and this is what I added to rocksdb's CMakeLists.
This basically finds grpc and protobuf's installation

```
# This branch assumes that gRPC and all its dependencies are already installed
  # on this system, so they can be located by find_package().

  # Find Protobuf installation
  # Looks for protobuf-config.cmake file installed by Protobuf's cmake installation.
  set(protobuf_MODULE_COMPATIBLE TRUE)
  find_package(Protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED)
  message(STATUS "Using protobuf ${Protobuf_VERSION}")

  set(_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF protobuf::libprotobuf)
  set(_REFLECTION gRPC::grpc++_reflection)
  if(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)
    find_program(_PROTOBUF_PROTOC protoc)
  else()
    set(_PROTOBUF_PROTOC $<TARGET_FILE:protobuf::protoc>)
  endif()

  # Find gRPC installation
  # Looks for gRPCConfig.cmake file installed by gRPC's cmake installation.
  find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)
  message(STATUS "Using gRPC ${gRPC_VERSION}")
  
  set(_GRPC_GRPCPP gRPC::grpc++)
  if(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)
    find_program(_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE grpc_cpp_plugin)
  else()
    set(_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE $<TARGET_FILE:gRPC::grpc_cpp_plugin>)
  endif()
```

Linking the rocksdb with grpc, protobuf

```
add_library(${ROCKSDB_STATIC_LIB} STATIC ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${ROCKSDB_STATIC_LIB} PRIVATE
  ${THIRDPARTY_LIBS} ${SYSTEM_LIBS} 
  ${_REFLECTION}
  ${_GRPC_GRPCPP}
  ${_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF}
  )
```

The Rocksdb compiles fine without error, but When I'm trying to use the compiled rocksdb library, It gives me a bunch of undefined reference.

```
mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/librocksdb.a(version_set.cc.o): In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/db/version_set.cc:4325: undefined reference to `grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials()'
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/db/version_set.cc:4324: undefined reference to `grpc::CreateChannel(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::shared_ptr<grpc::ChannelCredentials> const&)'
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/librocksdb.a(logAndApply.pb.cc.o): In function `logapply::Response::_InternalParse(char const*, google::protobuf::internal::ParseContext*)':
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/rubble/logAndApply/logAndApply.pb.cc:468: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::UnknownFieldParse(unsigned long, google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet*, char const*, google::protobuf::internal::ParseContext*)'
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/librocksdb.a(logAndApply.pb.cc.o): In function `logapply::Response::_InternalSerialize(unsigned char*, google::protobuf::io::EpsCopyOutputStream*) const':
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/rubble/logAndApply/logAndApply.pb.cc:497: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet::default_instance()'
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/rubble/logAndApply/logAndApply.pb.cc:497: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormat::InternalSerializeUnknownFieldsToArray(google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet const&, unsigned char*, google::protobuf::io::EpsCopyOutputStream*)'
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/librocksdb.a(logAndApply.pb.cc.o): In function `logapply::Response::ByteSizeLong() const':
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/rubble/logAndApply/logAndApply.pb.cc:519: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ComputeUnknownFieldsSize(google::protobuf::internal::InternalMetadata const&, unsigned long, google::protobuf::internal::CachedSize*)'
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/librocksdb.a(logAndApply.pb.cc.o): In function `logapply::Response::MergeFrom(google::protobuf::Message const&)':
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/rubble/logAndApply/logAndApply.pb.cc:534: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ReflectionOps::Merge(google::protobuf::Message const&, google::protobuf::Message*)'
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/librocksdb.a(logAndApply.pb.cc.o): In function `logapply::EditLists_EditList_VersionEdit::_InternalParse(char const*, google::protobuf::internal::ParseContext*)':
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/rubble/logAndApply/logAndApply.pb.cc:705: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::UnknownFieldParse(unsigned long, google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet*, char const*, google::protobuf::internal::ParseContext*)'
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/librocksdb.a(logAndApply.pb.cc.o): In function `logapply::EditLists_EditList_VersionEdit::_InternalSerialize(unsigned char*, google::protobuf::io::EpsCopyOutputStream*) const':
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/rubble/logAndApply/logAndApply.pb.cc:744: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet::default_instance()'
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/rubble/logAndApply/logAndApply.pb.cc:744: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormat::InternalSerializeUnknownFieldsToArray(google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet const&, unsigned char*, google::protobuf::io::EpsCopyOutputStream*)'
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/librocksdb.a(logAndApply.pb.cc.o): In function `logapply::EditLists::MergeFrom(google::protobuf::Message const&)':
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/rubble/logAndApply/logAndApply.pb.cc:1206: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ReflectionOps::Merge(google::protobuf::Message const&, google::protobuf::Message*)'
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/librocksdb.a(logAndApply.pb.cc.o): In function `logapply::NewFile_FileMetaData_FileDescriptor::_InternalParse(char const*, google::protobuf::internal::ParseContext*)':
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/rubble/logAndApply/logAndApply.pb.cc:1378: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::UnknownFieldParse(unsigned long, google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet*, char const*, google::protobuf::internal::ParseContext*)'
/root/local/include/google/protobuf/unknown_field_set.h:312: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet::ClearFallback()'
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/librocksdb.a(logAndApply.pb.cc.o): In function `google::protobuf::Message::Message()':
/root/local/include/google/protobuf/message.h:230: undefined reference to `vtable for google::protobuf::Message'
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/librocksdb.a(logAndApply.pb.cc.o): In function `google::protobuf::Message::Message(google::protobuf::Arena*)':
/root/local/include/google/protobuf/message.h:362: undefined reference to `vtable for google::protobuf::Message'
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/librocksdb.a(logAndApply.pb.cc.o): In function `logapply::Response::GetMetadataStatic()':
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/rubble/logAndApply/logAndApply.pb.h:207: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::AssignDescriptors(google::protobuf::internal::DescriptorTable const*, bool)'
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/librocksdb.a(logAndApply.pb.cc.o): In function `logapply::EditLists_EditList_VersionEdit::GetMetadataStatic()':
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/rubble/logAndApply/logAndApply.pb.h:344: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::AssignDescriptors(google::protobuf::internal::DescriptorTable const*, bool)'
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/librocksdb.a(logAndApply.pb.cc.o): In function `logapply::EditLists_EditList::GetMetadataStatic()':
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/rubble/logAndApply/logAndApply.pb.h:510: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::AssignDescriptors(google::protobuf::internal::DescriptorTable const*, bool)'
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/librocksdb.a(logAndApply.pb.cc.o): In function `logapply::EditLists::GetMetadataStatic()':
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/rubble/logAndApply/logAndApply.pb.h:658: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::AssignDescriptors(google::protobuf::internal::DescriptorTable const*, bool)'
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/librocksdb.a(logAndApply.pb.cc.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8logapply20NewFile_FileMetaDataE[_ZTVN8logapply20NewFile_FileMetaDataE]+0x98): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::SpaceUsedLong() const'
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/librocksdb.a(logAndApply.pb.cc.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8logapply35NewFile_FileMetaData_FileDescriptorE[_ZTVN8logapply35NewFile_FileMetaData_FileDescriptorE]+0x20): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::GetTypeName[abi:cxx11]() const'
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/librocksdb.a(logAndApply.pb.cc.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8logapply35NewFile_FileMetaData_FileDescriptorE[_ZTVN8logapply35NewFile_FileMetaData_FileDescriptorE]+0x48): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::InitializationErrorString[abi:cxx11]() const'
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/librocksdb.a(logAndApply.pb.cc.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8logapply35NewFile_FileMetaData_FileDescriptorE[_ZTVN8logapply35NewFile_FileMetaData_FileDescriptorE]+0x50): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::CheckTypeAndMergeFrom(google::protobuf::MessageLite const&)'
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/librocksdb.a(logAndApply.pb.cc.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8logapply35NewFile_FileMetaData_FileDescriptorE[_ZTVN8logapply35NewFile_FileMetaData_FileDescriptorE]+0x90): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::DiscardUnknownFields()'
(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN8logapply20NewFile_FileMetaDataE[_ZTIN8logapply20NewFile_FileMetaDataE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for google::protobuf::Message'
/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/librocksdb.a(logAndApply.pb.cc.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN8logapply35NewFile_FileMetaData_FileDescriptorE[_ZTIN8logapply35NewFile_FileMetaData_FileDescriptorE]+0x10): more undefined references to `typeinfo for google::protobuf::Message' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/primary_server.dir/build.make:143: recipe for target 'primary_server' failed
make[2]: *** [primary_server] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:98: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/primary_server.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/primary_server.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:102: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This is the CMakeLists file I wrote for my client program which uses the rocksdb library object

```
# Proto file
get_filename_component(kv_proto "../protos/keyvaluestore.proto" ABSOLUTE)
get_filename_component(kv_proto_path "${kv_proto}" PATH)

# Generated sources
set(kv_proto_srcs "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/keyvaluestore.pb.cc")
set(kv_proto_hdrs "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/keyvaluestore.pb.h")
set(kv_grpc_srcs "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/keyvaluestore.grpc.pb.cc")
set(kv_grpc_hdrs "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/keyvaluestore.grpc.pb.h")
add_custom_command(
      OUTPUT "${kv_proto_srcs}" "${kv_proto_hdrs}" "${kv_grpc_srcs}" "${kv_grpc_hdrs}"
      COMMAND ${_PROTOBUF_PROTOC}
      ARGS --grpc_out "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
        --cpp_out "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
        -I "${kv_proto_path}"
        --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc="${_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE}"
        "${kv_proto}"
      DEPENDS "${kv_proto}")

# Include generated *.pb.h files
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")

include_directories(/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/include)
link_directories(/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb)

# kv_grpc_proto
add_library(kv_grpc_proto
  ${kv_grpc_srcs}
  ${kv_grpc_hdrs}
  ${kv_proto_srcs}
  ${kv_proto_hdrs})
target_link_libraries(kv_grpc_proto
  ${_REFLECTION}
  ${_GRPC_GRPCPP}
  ${_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF}
  )

# Targets greeter_[async_](client|server)
foreach(_target
  kv_store_client
  primary_server
  )
  add_executable(${_target} "${_target}.cc")
  target_link_libraries(${_target}
    kv_grpc_proto
    ${_REFLECTION}
    ${_GRPC_GRPCPP}
    ${_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF}
    liblog_and_apply_grpc_proto.a
    librocksdb.a
    )
endforeach()
```

I'm not quite familiar with cmake, I think I didn't get it right when I'm trying to add the dependency into rocksdb's source code and I'm really kind of stuck on this, so any suggestions will be appreciated !

Comment: It seems you build your project with `make` utility. If this is true, then add `VERBOSE=1` option when call `make`. That way it will print all options passed to the linker. Check, that `grpc` and `protobuf` libraries are among these options.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for the comment. This is what I get after specifying ```VERBOSE=1```  Looks like it is not finding the library, but I'm still not sure why and how to fix it

Comment: ```Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/version_set.cc.o
/usr/bin/c++ -DCARES_STATICLIB -DGFLAGS=1 -DGFLAGS_IS_A_DLL=0  -I/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb -I/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/include -I/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/third-party/folly -isystem /root/local/include -W -Wextra -Wall -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Woverloaded-virtual -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-strict-aliasing -march=native -Werror -fno-builtin-memcmp -g -DROCKSDB_USE_RTTI -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/version_set.cc.o -c /mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb/db/version_set.cc```

Comment: Wait.. Does this finds the libraries? My  ```protoc``` and ```grpc``` are installed under ```/root/local/```  The output says ```-isystem /root/local/include```. Not sure if it finds the lib..

Comment: No, this is not the command line you need to check. You need to check **linker** command line (which causes "undefined reference" errors), not the **compiler** command line.

Comment: Also, you may to check values of variables `_GRPC_GRPCPP` and `_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF` which you pass to the `target_link_libraries` call. E.g. you may add `message(STATUS "_GRPC_GRPCPP: ${_GRPC_GRPCPP}")` near that call. If printed value is empty, then the variable is not set correctly. (You have complex code which sets variables, so it is difficult to say whether it works correctly without running it).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Sorry I forgot to include the ```cmake ``` output, running ```cmake .``` under the rocksdb source directory gives ```root@node-0:/mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb# cmake . 

-- Enabling RTTI in Debug builds only (default)
Protobuf_LIBRARIES: /root/local/lib/libprotobuf.a
-- Using protobuf 3.13.0.0
-- Using gRPC 1.34.0
-- JNI library is disabled
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /mnt/sdb/my_rocksdb ```
So I think it's finding the package.

Comment: "So I think it's finding the package" - Yes, `find_package` probably finds the package. But it could be that you use results of `find_package` **incorrectly**. That is why I ask you to check value of variables `_GRPC_GRPCPP` and `_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF`.

Comment: As for the checking a command line, you need to check the command line for the **command causing errors**. The command described as `Linking CXX static library librocksdb.a` cannot cause "undefined reference" error because it creates a **static** library. A creation of a static library does NOT call **linker**. (Instead, it calls an *archiver* utility, `/usr/bin/ar`).

Answer (score 0):

The `linker` output seems is not linking `libprotobuf.a` and `libgrpcpp.a`

```
[100%] Linking CXX static library librocksdb.a
/usr/local/bin/cmake -P CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/ar qc librocksdb.a CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/cache/cache.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/cache/clock_cache.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/cache/lru_cache.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/cache/sharded_cache.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/arena_wrapped_db_iter.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/blob/blob_file_addition.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/blob/blob_file_builder.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/blob/blob_file_cache.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/blob/blob_file_garbage.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/blob/blob_file_meta.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/blob/blob_file_reader.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/blob/blob_log_format.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/blob/blob_log_sequential_reader.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/blob/blob_log_writer.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/builder.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/c.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/column_family.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/compacted_db_impl.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/compaction/compaction.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/compaction/compaction_iterator.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/compaction/compaction_picker.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/compaction/compaction_job.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/compaction/compaction_picker_fifo.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/compaction/compaction_picker_level.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/compaction/compaction_picker_universal.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/compaction/sst_partitioner.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/convenience.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/db_filesnapshot.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/db_impl/db_impl.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/db_impl/db_impl_write.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/db_impl/db_impl_compaction_flush.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/db_impl/db_impl_files.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/db_impl/db_impl_open.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/db_impl/db_impl_debug.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/db_impl/db_impl_experimental.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/db_impl/db_impl_readonly.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/db_impl/db_impl_secondary.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/db_info_dumper.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/db_iter.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/dbformat.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/error_handler.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/event_helpers.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/experimental.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/external_sst_file_ingestion_job.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/file_indexer.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/flush_job.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/flush_scheduler.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/forward_iterator.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/import_column_family_job.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/internal_stats.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/logs_with_prep_tracker.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/log_reader.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/log_writer.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/malloc_stats.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/memtable.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/memtable_list.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/merge_helper.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/merge_operator.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/output_validator.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/periodic_work_scheduler.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/range_del_aggregator.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/range_tombstone_fragmenter.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/repair.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/snapshot_impl.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/table_cache.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/table_properties_collector.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/transaction_log_impl.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/trim_history_scheduler.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/version_builder.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/version_edit.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/version_edit_handler.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/version_set.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/wal_edit.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/wal_manager.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/write_batch.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/write_batch_base.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/write_controller.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/db/write_thread.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/env/env.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/env/env_chroot.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/env/env_encryption.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/env/env_hdfs.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/env/file_system.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/env/file_system_tracer.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/env/mock_env.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/file/delete_scheduler.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/file/file_prefetch_buffer.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/file/file_util.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/file/filename.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/file/random_access_file_reader.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/file/read_write_util.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/file/readahead_raf.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/file/sequence_file_reader.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/file/sst_file_manager_impl.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/file/writable_file_writer.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/logging/auto_roll_logger.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/logging/event_logger.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/logging/log_buffer.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/memory/arena.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/memory/concurrent_arena.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/memory/jemalloc_nodump_allocator.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/memory/memkind_kmem_allocator.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/memtable/alloc_tracker.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/memtable/hash_linklist_rep.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/memtable/hash_skiplist_rep.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/memtable/skiplistrep.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/memtable/vectorrep.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/memtable/write_buffer_manager.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/monitoring/histogram.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/monitoring/histogram_windowing.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/monitoring/in_memory_stats_history.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/monitoring/instrumented_mutex.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/monitoring/iostats_context.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/monitoring/perf_context.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/monitoring/perf_level.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/monitoring/persistent_stats_history.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/monitoring/statistics.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/monitoring/thread_status_impl.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/monitoring/thread_status_updater.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/monitoring/thread_status_util.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/monitoring/thread_status_util_debug.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/options/cf_options.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/options/configurable.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/options/db_options.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/options/options.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/options/options_helper.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/options/options_parser.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/port/stack_trace.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/adaptive/adaptive_table_factory.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/block_based/binary_search_index_reader.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/block_based/block.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/block_based/block_based_filter_block.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/block_based/block_based_table_builder.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/block_based/block_based_table_factory.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/block_based/block_based_table_iterator.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/block_based/block_based_table_reader.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/block_based/block_builder.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/block_based/block_prefetcher.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/block_based/block_prefix_index.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/block_based/data_block_hash_index.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/block_based/data_block_footer.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/block_based/filter_block_reader_common.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/block_based/filter_policy.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/block_based/flush_block_policy.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/block_based/full_filter_block.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/block_based/hash_index_reader.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/block_based/index_builder.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/block_based/index_reader_common.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/block_based/parsed_full_filter_block.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/block_based/partitioned_filter_block.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/block_based/partitioned_index_iterator.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/block_based/partitioned_index_reader.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/block_based/reader_common.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/block_based/uncompression_dict_reader.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/block_fetcher.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/cuckoo/cuckoo_table_builder.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/cuckoo/cuckoo_table_factory.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/cuckoo/cuckoo_table_reader.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/format.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/get_context.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/iterator.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/merging_iterator.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/meta_blocks.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/persistent_cache_helper.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/plain/plain_table_bloom.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/plain/plain_table_builder.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/plain/plain_table_factory.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/plain/plain_table_index.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/plain/plain_table_key_coding.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/plain/plain_table_reader.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/sst_file_dumper.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/sst_file_reader.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/sst_file_writer.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/table_factory.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/table_properties.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/table/two_level_iterator.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/test_util/sync_point.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/test_util/sync_point_impl.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/test_util/testutil.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/test_util/transaction_test_util.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/tools/block_cache_analyzer/block_cache_trace_analyzer.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/tools/dump/db_dump_tool.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/tools/io_tracer_parser_tool.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/tools/ldb_cmd.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/tools/ldb_tool.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/tools/sst_dump_tool.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/tools/trace_analyzer_tool.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/trace_replay/trace_replay.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/trace_replay/block_cache_tracer.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/trace_replay/io_tracer.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/util/coding.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/util/compaction_job_stats_impl.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/util/comparator.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/util/compression_context_cache.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/util/concurrent_task_limiter_impl.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/util/crc32c.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/util/dynamic_bloom.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/util/hash.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/util/murmurhash.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/util/random.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/util/rate_limiter.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/util/slice.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/util/file_checksum_helper.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/util/status.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/util/string_util.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/util/thread_local.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/util/threadpool_imp.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/util/xxhash.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/backupable/backupable_db.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/blob_db/blob_compaction_filter.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/blob_db/blob_db.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/blob_db/blob_db_impl.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/blob_db/blob_db_impl_filesnapshot.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/blob_db/blob_dump_tool.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/blob_db/blob_file.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/cassandra/cassandra_compaction_filter.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/cassandra/format.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/cassandra/merge_operator.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/checkpoint/checkpoint_impl.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/compaction_filters/remove_emptyvalue_compactionfilter.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/debug.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/env_mirror.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/env_timed.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/fault_injection_env.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/fault_injection_fs.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/leveldb_options/leveldb_options.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/memory/memory_util.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/merge_operators/bytesxor.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/merge_operators/max.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/merge_operators/put.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/merge_operators/sortlist.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/merge_operators/string_append/stringappend.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/merge_operators/string_append/stringappend2.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/merge_operators/uint64add.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/object_registry.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/option_change_migration/option_change_migration.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/options/options_util.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/persistent_cache/block_cache_tier.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/persistent_cache/block_cache_tier_file.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/persistent_cache/block_cache_tier_metadata.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/persistent_cache/persistent_cache_tier.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/persistent_cache/volatile_tier_impl.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/simulator_cache/cache_simulator.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/simulator_cache/sim_cache.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/table_properties_collectors/compact_on_deletion_collector.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/trace/file_trace_reader_writer.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/transactions/lock/lock_manager.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/transactions/lock/point/point_lock_tracker.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/transactions/lock/point/point_lock_manager.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/transactions/optimistic_transaction_db_impl.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/transactions/optimistic_transaction.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/transactions/pessimistic_transaction.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/transactions/pessimistic_transaction_db.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/transactions/snapshot_checker.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/transactions/transaction_base.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/transactions/transaction_db_mutex_impl.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/transactions/transaction_util.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/transactions/write_prepared_txn.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/transactions/write_prepared_txn_db.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/transactions/write_unprepared_txn.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/transactions/write_unprepared_txn_db.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/ttl/db_ttl_impl.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/write_batch_with_index/write_batch_with_index.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/utilities/write_batch_with_index/write_batch_with_index_internal.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/rubble/logAndApply/logAndApply.grpc.pb.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/rubble/logAndApply/logAndApply.pb.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/port/port_posix.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/env/env_posix.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/env/fs_posix.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/env/io_posix.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/third-party/folly/folly/detail/Futex.cpp.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/third-party/folly/folly/synchronization/AtomicNotification.cpp.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/third-party/folly/folly/synchronization/DistributedMutex.cpp.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/third-party/folly/folly/synchronization/ParkingLot.cpp.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/third-party/folly/folly/synchronization/WaitOptions.cpp.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/logAndApply.grpc.pb.cc.o CMakeFiles/rocksdb.dir/logAndApply.pb.cc.o CMakeFiles/build_version.dir/build_version.cc.o
/usr/bin/ranlib librocksdb.a
```

doing a `grep` on the output on `grpc` and `protobuf` didn't give me the library... So linker somehow fails to find the lib, which is confusing to me cause I did a

```
target_link_libraries(${ROCKSDB_STATIC_LIB} PRIVATE
  ${THIRDPARTY_LIBS} ${SYSTEM_LIBS} 
  ${_REFLECTION}
  ${_GRPC_GRPCPP}
  ${_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF}
  )
```

in rocksdb's `CMakeLists`.

Comment: Please note, that on Stack Overflow the **answer post** is supposed to contain an **answer** to the question. If you just want to post additional information about your problem, then add this information to the **question post**.